# I am trying to invoke another function outside a javascript object on initialize by return the outer function

Tags: javascript, function, object, return

Why does this not work? I am trying to invoke the inner function "refreshPage".

```
var myFunc = function(){

  var refreshPage = function(){
    alert("hello");
  };

  return { 
    refreshPage: refreshPage
  };

}();

function refreshPage(){
  return myFunc.refreshPage(); 
}
```

http://jsbin.com/eYIXAxaM/2/

Comment: You need to invoke `refreshPage();` as well

Comment: I do it with return { refreshPage: refreshPage }; Why does this not work?

Comment: But you are calling it within a function `refreshPage` which you are not invoking. see this http://jsbin.com/ICisAmEg/1

Comment: Adding the empty parenthesis is invoking it I thought.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var myFunc = function(){

  var refreshPage = function(){
    alert("hello");
  };

  return { 
    refreshPage: refreshPage
  };

}();

function refreshPage(){
  return myFunc.refreshPage(); 
}
refreshPage();
```

I think the problem will be clearer if we rename and relocate some things.

```
/* sayHello will be a function: */
function sayHello() {
    alert("hello");
}
/* makeObjectWithMethod will be a function: */
function makeObjectWithMethod() {
    /* equivalently, assign sayHello to the variable refreshPage, but don't invoke */
    var refreshPage = sayHello;
    /* return an *object* with a property, refreshPage, whose value is the function */
    /* sayHello - not the value it returns, but the function itself. */
    return {
        refreshPage: refreshPage
    };
}
/* make a variable called myFunc whose value is the object returned by above */
var myFunc = makeObjectWithMethod();
/* make a method called finallyReallyDoIt that *when invoked*, calls a method */
/* of myFunc named refreshPage */
function finallyReallyDoIt() {
    return myFunc.refreshPage();
}
```

If you never call `finallyReallyDoIt`, all you've done is created the `myFunc` object and *declared* `finallyReallyDoIt` as a function.  Much like `sayHello` and `makeObjectWithMethod` above it, `finallyReallyDoIt` doesn't happen until you call it somewhere.

Comment: Thank you. Makes more sense now.